# Not able to plot graph: matplotlib is needed for plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, memory-profiling, guppy

I am able to generate *.dat file:

```
vikas@server:~/memory_profiler-0.36$ ./mprof run --python test_sl.py 
vikas@server:~/memory_profiler-0.36$ ls *.dat
mprofile_20151001035123.dat
```

But when I am trying to plot graph then it is saying "matplotlib is needed for plotting"

```
vikas@server:~/memory_profiler-0.36$ ./mprof plot --output=plot.png 
matplotlib is needed for plotting.
```

Did I miss anything?

Function I am profiling is run() which is inside: file_to_be_profiled.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import os, sys, commands
from memory_profiler import profile
from guppy import hpy

@profile
def run():
    d = {}
    l = []
    hp = hpy()
    before = hp.heap()

    d["k1"] = 'val1'
    d["k2"] = 10
    count = 0
    while (count < 9):
        l.append(count)
        print 'The count is:', count
        count = count + 1
    print "Good bye!"
    after = hp.heap()
    leftover = after - before
    print leftover

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(run())
```

And I am invoking run() from my test script: test_sl.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import commands

# for the time being I am running my test to profile method: run() inside file_to_be_profiled.py
run_cmd = './file_to_be_profiled.py
commands.getstatusoutput(run_cmd)
```

I am running on ubuntu machine. But apt-get install did not worked for me. Then I did the install from source. But then also I am getting same error.

apt-get failed:

```
vikas@server:~/memory_profiler-0.36$ sudo apt-get install -y python-matplotlib
[sudo] password for vikaskuk:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python-matplotlib is not available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-matplotlib' has no installation candidate
vikask@server:~/memory_profiler-0.36$ ./mprof plot --output=plot.png
matplotlib is needed for plotting.
```

Then I attempted pip install... which also did not go through:

```
vikas@server:~/memory_profiler-0.36$ pip install matplotlib
Downloading/unpacking matplotlib
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement matplotlib
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for matplotlib
Storing debug log for failure in /home/vikaskuk/.pip/pip.log
```

Finally I tried installing from source which seems to be succeeded:

```
vikas@server:~/memory_profiler-0.36$ cd ../matplotlib
vikas@server:~/matplotlib$ cd matplotlib-master/

(virtualenv)vikaskuk@beehive:~/matplotlib/matplotlib-master$ vi INSTALL
(virtualenv)vikaskuk@beehive:~/matplotlib/matplotlib-master$ python setup.py build
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.5.dev1]
                python: yes [2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 16:22:56)  [GCC
                        4.4.5]]
              platform: yes [linux2]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
                   six: yes [using six version 1.5.2]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.1]
                  pytz: yes [pytz was not found. pip will attempt to install
                        it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                        could not be found.  You may need to install the
                        development package.]
                   png: no  [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                        be found.]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: yes [using nose version 1.3.0 / using mock 1.0.1]
        toolkits_tests: yes [using nose version 1.3.0 / using mock 1.0.1]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: no  [The C/C++ header for Tk (tk.h) could not be
                        found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: yes [version 8.71]
                 latex: yes [version 3.1415926]
               pdftops: no

============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype, png
(virtualenv)vikaskuk@beehive:~/matplotlib/matplotlib-master$ python setup.py install
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.5.dev1]
                python: yes [2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 16:22:56)  [GCC
                        4.4.5]]
              platform: yes [linux2]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
                   six: yes [using six version 1.5.2]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.1]
                  pytz: yes [pytz was not found. pip will attempt to install
                        it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                        could not be found.  You may need to install the
                        development package.]
                   png: no  [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                        be found.]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: yes [using nose version 1.3.0 / using mock 1.0.1]
        toolkits_tests: yes [using nose version 1.3.0 / using mock 1.0.1]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: no  [The C/C++ header for Tk (tk.h) could not be
                        found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: yes [version 8.71]
                 latex: yes [version 3.1415926]
               pdftops: no

============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype, png
```

But when I try to plot the graph I hit the original issue:

```
vikas@server:~/matplotlib/matplotlib-master$ cd ../../memory_profiler-0.36
vikas@server:~/memory_profiler-0.36$ ./mprof plot --output=plot.png 
matplotlib is needed for plotting.
```

I was able to successfully do apt-get update(there was some firewall issue and then I successfully did: sudo apt-get install -y python-matplotlib.

But still I am getting some issue while running mprof:

```
vikas@server:~/memory_profiler-0.36$ ./mprof plot --output=plot.png
Using last profile data.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mprof", line 494, in <module>
    actions[get_action()]()
  File "./mprof", line 454, in plot_action
    pl.figure(figsize=(14, 6), dpi=90)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 423, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 79, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 87, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1767, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Why do I need to set the display? I am working on ubuntu hosted machine.

Comment: Actually, your build from source didn't succeed either.  You don't have `freetype` or `libpng` installed on your machine, so matplotlib can't build.  `pip install` ran into a separate issue (are you behind a firewall?), but would have hit that same snag shortly thereafter.  I'm not sure why you're having issues installing through the package manager, but apt-get install `libfreetype6-dev`, `libpng-dev`, and `python-tk` and then you should be able to build from source.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `matplotlib`, as instructed ([this error in thrown by `mprof` when it can't find `matplotlib`](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler/blob/0e53367d24128ed4960c0f8210e8d046303c2a9d/mprof#L337)).

You can do so using pip `pip install matplotlib` (you might need to prefix this with `sudo`) or your package manager:

- `sudo apt-get install -y python-matplotlib` on Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives.
- `sudo yum install -y python-matplotlib` on RHEL, CentOS and derivatives.

Comment: I am running on ubuntu machine. But apt-get install did not worked for me. Then I did the install from source. Editing the question with the steps what I did.

Comment: @vikas Make sure you explain why `apt-get install` did not work for you. Is there an error message?

Comment: There may be some kind of firewall in my organisation... thats why apt-get would have failed. Thus I attempted source install which looks like did succeed. But then also original issue persist. Please see my original question.... i've edited now with what all I did.

Comment: @vikas No, the source installation failed (see the end of the output). Try running `sudo apt-get update` before you run `apt-get install`. You are going to need to make `apt-get` work at some point, because you're missing a lot of dependencies for `matplotlib` and `apt-get` is realistically the only way to get them.

Comment: post successfull apt-get update I was able to install matplotlib... but still mprof complains about display. Please have a look on the original question. I've cited with the error I am getting.

Answer (score 3):

It seems matplotlib: 3.0.1 does not go well with  python 3.7 in conda environment. 
df.plot() command could not be executed properly showing "ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting" but actually matplotlib is installed.

I tried to downgrade matplotlib to 3.0.0 then everything is fine.

conda install -n [your_conda_envionment] matplotlib==3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem on freshely installed Ubuntu 16.04. To solve it, I have installed SciPy like this:

`sudo pip install scipy`

Also I had to install `tkinter` lib like this:

`sudo apt-get install python-tk`

I guess somewhere in the past, matplotlib had `scipy` as dependency, but now it only has numpy, while `mprof plot` requires `scipy`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used memory_profiler lib typing this commands
(`mprof run runner.py` and `mprof plot`) and got a message "matplotlib is needed for plotting"

I tried to get rid of this problem following advice I found here but in the result I solved this problem completing these simple steps:

1. delete files in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ connected with matplotlib (or you can uninstall matplotlib using the ordinary way)
2. use `sudo yum-builddep python-matplotlib` to install connected packages (222 packages were installed, if you need apt-get, you need this command: `sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib`)
3. install matplotlib `sudo yum reinstall python-matplotlib` (or use install command, with apt-get: `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib`)

I believe this will help.